# The scope of a declaration in C++ template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

For the following code:

```cpp
namespace A
{
    struct B
    {
        using type = std::tuple<struct C>;
    };
}

int main()
{
    C* ptr = nullptr;
    B::C* ptr2 = nullptr;
    A::B::C* ptr3 = nullptr;
    A::C* ptr4 = nullptr;
}
```

I just want to know what is the scope of `C`. I have tried in gcc 6.5/7.4/8.3/9.1 and clang 6/7/8, they all told me that `A::C` is correct. But I am not sure whether there are any materials in the C++ standard that describe the scope of `C` in the above situation.

Could you tell me if you know the materials in the C++ standard that related to this topic? Thanks very much !

Comment: Is the lack of *definition* of `C` on purpose?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Pretty sure it is, otherwise the scope would be clear, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is detailed in the C++ standard at the following sections:

> **[basic.lookup.elab]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.elab#2) If the elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by the class-key
>   and this lookup does not find a previously declared type-name, or if
>   the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> ```
>    class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
> ```
>
> the elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in [basic.scope.pdecl].
>
> **[basic.scope.pdecl]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.pdecl#7) The point of declaration of a class first declared in an
>   elaborated-type-specifier is as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - ... if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or parameter-declaration-clause of a function
>     defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a class-name
>     in the namespace that contains the declaration; **otherwise, except as
>     a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the smallest
>     namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.**

The argument list of a template falls in the "otherwise" clause. `A` is the smallest namespace that contains the declaration, so the class type `C` is declared inside of it. `A::C` is the correct way to refer to it.

Comment: *'or block scope'* – could it be unclear to question author that the class braces don't form a block scope? If so, then perhaps better mention?